# Reboot ML350 G4 Server in sealed room

Tags: local-area-network, hp-proliant, boot

I have an old server in a remote location. It has its own power feed which is subject to failure twice a month. The problem with this failure is that it does not simply drop and recover hours later. It drops, recovers for 5 min, drops again, recovers for minutes then might drop again etc. So I don’t want to set the server to reboot on AC being restored. I want to wait until I think that the AC is stable.

Many modern BIOS allow one to reboot on mouse, keyboard and (I think) LAN activity.

As I can’t access the server location easily , does anyone have first hand experience of what reboot on LAN activity means or am I confused and BIOSs only have the ability to boot from a LAN. If the server can only be set to boot from the LAN and not because of LAN activity is there a way to disable whatever is providing the means for the server to boot from the LAN until I am happy that the AC is stable.

Thanks

Comment: out of curiosity, does the server have iLO configured?

Comment: Is this server not on a UPS?

Comment: Not sure. Still have to do learn the ins and out of this machine.

Comment: No. UPS make lots of beeping noises when they wish to draw attention to their plight. I don't really want to have to modify a UPS to not beep.

Comment: TBH, that sounds a little silly. The only time I could see this being an issue is if the UPS was in a public area where it would bother others. However, you said its remote and locked away...

Comment: And, whats more annoying, a server power cycling over and over, or a beeping UPS?

Comment: Its in an old giant house. The type you see on "Remains of the Day" or "Sense & Sensibility". I am in a different building with a wifi link to routers in the old house. There is an 'elderly' gentlemen who is conviced a plague of rats occupies his wing due to the noises of technology that come from the attic. (Should start on my screen play already and flog the plot to Hollywood)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This server has iLO management port that can be used, among other things, to control power state of the system. That would be the most appropriate and reliable way to power up the server. Just connect a network cable, configure IP address (can be done from the host OS using HP Proliant Support Pack utilities), and you're good.

However, I can't understand why you're willing to suffer through such power outages, if they can be made a non-issue with an inexpensive UPS unit. A unit that would power you server for half an hour, and have a network management card allowing you to control power from your location, would cost about $500 or so.

Comment: Again if I can find a black ops whisper quiet UPS that dosen't beep while its carring the load then I shall purchase it.

Comment: Sounds like you need a new server location

Comment: Yes. Thinking Marsellies on the French Coast

Comment: I used to have an UPS where the beeping drove me insane (it was in my bedroom).  I took the front casing off, and replaced the beeper with a blue LED.  Quiet.. and Blue.

Answer (score 1):

The "reboot on LAN activity" is most likely [Wake-on-LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) support. You just need to find the right tool for your environment to generate the WOL Magic packet.